# QPixmaps in PyQt don't get cleaned up properly when made directly from file and not from QImage

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

Consider the following code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtNetwork, QtWebKit


class ImageView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, file):
        super().__init__()
        self.setScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene())
        f = QtGui.QPixmap(QtGui.QImage(file))
        # f = QtGui.QPixmap(file)
        item = QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem(f)
        self.scene().addItem(item)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.scene().clear()

image = 'big.png'
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
view = ImageView(image)
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

Here I load a big (10000x10000px) image and display it in a QGraphicsView, and the scene then can be cleared with a mouse click. If the line `f = QtGui.QPixmap(QtGui.QImage(file))` is used, then after clearing the scene the memory usage drops from 400 Mb to 20, showing that the image is cleared from memory. However, if I replace that line with `f = QtGui.QPixmap(file)`, then after the same action memory usage remains at 400 Mb. It doesn't get reallocated later, either - if after clearing the scene I create another ImageView with another big image, another chunk gets allocated. Moreover, when I create QPixmap directly from file, I cannot free up the memory in any way whatsoever - I tried Python's `deleteLater`, `del` and gc module. This happens both in PyQt and Pyside. Why is this happening?

Comment: Try: `QPixmapCache.clear()`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Wow, that helped. Two questions: 1) Qt docs say that the cache limit on desktop is 10 Mb. Why is it getting way larger than that? 2) Why doesn't this happen when making it from QImage?

Comment: (1) Not sure. Probably need to read the source to see what is actually going on. (2) It's only the `QPixmap` methods that take a filename that do automatic caching.

Comment: All right, please make this an answer and I'll accept it. I think this is the correct procedure for receiving an explanation in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QPixmap` methods that take a filename will do automatic caching via a `QPixmapCache`. So it should be possible to free up memory like this:

```
QPixmapCache.clear()
```

The Qt docs state that the cache limit for `QPixmapCache` is 10mb for desktop systems. However, this limit may be exceeded in practice. The reasons for this are somewhat obscure, but looking at the source reveals that Qt uses a [QCache](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcache.html), and sets its *maxCost* to `cache_limit * 1024`. However, the docs for [totalCost](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcache.html#totalCost) say that this may be exceeded for implicitly shared classes (such as `QPixmap`).